# cant click facebook page's LIKE button using python selenium

Tags: javascript, python, facebook, selenium, automation

So here is the code for (FB page like button):

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div/div[4]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div/div[1]'))).click()
```

cant be clicked
I don't know whether its the right Xpath or not.

Comment: You know that that XPath can change any moment? And it may not be the same in your browser and when selenium checks the page. Also Facebook don't allow you to scrape them. You have to use the API. And linking stuff is not possible in the API.

Comment: _“cant click facebook page's LIKE button using python selenium”_ - good! It means their anti-spam /anti-fraud measures are working.

Answer (score 1):

I found the same problem and I resolved finding the like button by the css selector and not by the xpath

Answer (score 0):

1. You should focus on unique class name and create any xpath manually.
2. Maybe focus on some basic xpath course to learn how to do it like on course below:

> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9-iVt0MIqNY